# PHP MySQL: managing and manipulating contents

Tags: php, mysql

Dear all my brothers and sisters. I am integrating HTML & PHP with MySql. 
And what I need help is. How to authenticate users before changing password using their email address?

The following is what I tried:

This is my: the **Change Passowrd.html** form

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>    

    <body>

    <h2>Change Your Password</h2>

    <form name="passwd" action="passwd.php" method="POST">   

    E-Mil:<input type="text" name="email" ><br>
Old Password:<input type="text" name="old_password" ><br>
New Password:<input type="text" name="new_password" ><br>
Confirm Password:<input type="text" name="confirm_password" >
<input type="submit" value="Update" width="5">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my: **changpassword.php** script file

*Example: I want to change the password 'nuru' to 'selam' whose usermail is: nur_selam@yahoo.com and match previous password.*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ChangePassowrd</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$tablename="users";
//connect the server & select database
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("cannor connect");
mysql_select_db('fb')or die("cannort select DB");

//Get values from FORM
$mail=$_POST['email'];
$oldpswd=$_POST['old_password'];
$newpswd=$_POST['new_password'];
$conpswd=$_POST['confirm_password'];


mysql_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The mysql extension is deprecated. It would be advisable to use either [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code
    
    
    Password Updater

```
<?php

$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$tablename="users";
//connect the server & select database
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("cannor connect");
mysql_select_db('fb')or die("cannort select DB");

//Get values from FORM
$mail=$_POST['email'];
$oldpswd=$_POST['old_password'];
$newpswd=$_POST['new_password'];
$conpswd=$_POST['confirm_password'];

$query = mysql_query("select * from users where email = '$mail'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  if($row['pass'] == $oldpswd)
  {
    mysql_query("update users set pass = '$newpswd' where email = '$mail'"); 
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Wrong password.";
    exit();
  }
}

mysql_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks anilmp40, Your suggestion works perfectly. Now I can update password & manage exceptions.

Comment: if my answer helped you so please mark it as an accepted answer.